# How can I merge two specific lines with sed?

Tags: unix, sed, solaris

I have a file that looks like this

```
line one
line two
line three
line four
```

and I want it to look like this (I want lines 2 and 3 merged into one)

```
line one
line two line three
line four
```

I've tried the following, that based on my research SHOULD do what I want:

```
$ sed '2s/\n/ /' test.txt > test2.txt
```

However `test2.txt` looks like this

```
line one
line two
line three
line four
```

I've seen some references to it being different on Solaris than Linux. Here's my server's details

```
$ uname -a
SunOS myserver 5.10 Generic_142909-17 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490
```

How can I make this give the results I want?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) which explains why it's a bit difficult with sed.

Comment: Do you want to merge the second line with the third, or the line with `line two` with `line three` regardless of position they have in the file?

Comment: it was based upon line number, not the values of the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answers in the linked question, this sed should work:

```
sed '2N;s/\n/ /' file
```

`2N` means on the second line, append the next line to the pattern space. This results in the pattern space containing `line two\nline three`. The substitution (which replaces the newline `\n` with a space) applies to every line in the file but only has an effect here.

Otherwise, this awk would do the trick:

```
awk 'NR==2{printf("%s ",$0);next}1' file
```

On line two, use `printf` to print the contents of the line, followed by a space. `next` skips to the next line. For all other lines, the `1` at the end is effectively a `{print $0}` block (which prints the line).

Alternatively:

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$0,NR==2?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

Where `OFS` by default is a space and `ORS` is a newline

Or a bit of perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if $. == 2' file
```

`$.` is the line number. Substitute the newline for a space on the 2nd line.

Output (using any of the above approaches on my system):

```
line one
line two line three
line four
```

Comment: I get 'awk: syntax error near line 1'
'awk: bailing out near line 1'

Comment: @CodeSlave Since you are on solaris, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of regular `awk`. Also, the `sed` won't work as solaris `sed` does not recognize `\n` character like GNU and other variants do.

Comment: @jaypal so would a `^M` (ctrl-v return) work on Solaris?

Comment: Ok, the sed and the perl examples work which is good enough for my purposes.

Comment: I'm assuming the 2N; is indicating to work on line 2 and the next line, and my first try was just working on the line 2 (and not including the new line when I was trying to replace)

Comment: @TomFenech No idea don't have a solaris box handy, but I remember adding a newline was a big pain and had to force an implicit newline (hitting enter). Replacing a newline might not be that difficult. UPDATE: and so it seems!

Comment: @CodeSlave I have added to my explanation in the answer, hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: @TomFenech thanks for going above and beyond. I can only up-vote you once, so here's another on anotherone of your good answers as a bonus :-)